# Storing socket object into localStorage for later use

Tags: javascript, json, dom, socket.io, local-storage

I am trying to create an application where the client-side socket object of socket.io will be used across multiple documents. So, I am trying to store the socket object in localStorage, in order to be able to use it in javaScript files of other documents. But it seems not to work.

I am storing the socket object like this (here it works well):-

```
function login(){
    return new Promise((resolve , reject)=>{
      try{
        localStorage.setItem('socket' , JSON.stringify( JSON.decycle( io() ) ) );
        resolve();
      } catch(error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    })
  }
```

And then later trying to retrieve it in this way:-

```
login()
.then(()=>{
   let soc = localStorage.getItem('socket');
   alert(soc);
   soc = JSON.retrocycle( JSON.parse(soc) );
   soc.emit("user_login",data);
})
```

But the socket doesn't seem to restore properly and throws the error: `TypeError: soc.emit is not a function`

**So, my question is :-**
How is it possible to achieve my goal and where am I going wrong? If it is not possible using localStorage, then suggest me some other way to achieve this. As I am new to socket.io, I would also appreciate any socket.io related solution to achieve my goal.

Comment: io is not a valid object for storing to localhost =) What do you want to keep on client side?

Comment: @HalilÇakar Is there any turnaround then? Basically I want to store the io object because I don't want the client to get disconnected on closing the document and also because I want to use the io object on multiple documents rather than only one.

Comment: I'm assuming that there wont be a working way what you asked. Multiple docs can have multiple connections actually there is nothing wrong with that. And let's assume that you could, how it would work then if you have 2 tabs open with differente url's or even with the same. I'm not sure really but i can say that i'm 90% sure that you won't be able to store and reconnect with same io. When you think everytime you connect a website it load assets and scripts so.. Maybe if you can explane why you want to store that we might think something on it?

Comment: @HalilÇakar Thank you, that was helpful. Answer to your question: Actually when a user is logging in, I am storing the socket-id along with the username in the server. The socket-ids are being used later for private communication between the users in a different document, so I don't want the socket-ids to get destroyed. The socket-id should destroy only on logging out. Sadly, I don't have much experience with socket.io. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Sure! Glad to be helpful. So If you have an auth system already then you might use their own uniq id's. There is an `AUTH` connection io. you can use `io.use('authorization', () => {})` as a middleware to get thier data from database. I'm using this auth middleware to get user's data from their session payload and parse it and use their data for instance :)

Comment: @HalilÇakar Do you mean we can create custom ids to identify each socket rather than its own id? Then maybe that's what I wanted. No idea how auth works on socket.io and their documentation wasn't of great help either. Could you describe the process with an example code and post it as an answer? That would be of great help. Actually I have used a turnaround, but a perfect solution would help in the latter part of development. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure i can but first i need to know if you have a auth system already, what is your backend working on? After that maybe i can create an example code for you :)

Comment: @HalilÇakar Yes. I am using Sequelize and Passport.js for authentication working on express framework. Usernames can be treated as a unique-ids here.

Comment: Aight, create a global USERS object and use user's Sequelize id to store their data as much as you like should be the way. But i really can't produce an example case because i don't have that much Sequelize and Passport.js experiens :(

Comment: @HalilÇakar Nevermind. Thank you for your time and help. The hint you gave certainly helped me to figure out a turnaround. Thank you so much :)